# Fedora 26 upgrade fails

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I cannot upgrade my Fedora 25 -> 26.
I issue `dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=26 --allowerasing` and then `dnf system-upgrade reboot`. Everything works fine up to the point when the message about ongoing upgrade shows up. After several seconds my laptop just reboots straight back into Fedora 25. Here is my [dnf log](https://gist.github.com/a5779396a069e067409af8cb3429d9f7).

Answer (score 1):

Around line 2297 is where it fails:

```
Jul 24 00:36:00 lisbook audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jul 24 00:36:00 lisbook kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1500849360.297:92): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jul 24 00:36:04 lisbook mbpfan[733]: Old Temp 79: New Temp: 79, Fan Speed: 2000
Jul 24 00:36:04 lisbook mbpfan[733]: Sleeping for 7 seconds
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: dnf-system-upgrade.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: dnf-system-upgrade.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: dnf-system-upgrade.service: Failed to run 'stop-post' task: No such file or directory
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-system-upgrade comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: dnf-system-upgrade.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1500849369.956:93): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-system-upgrade comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: dnf-system-upgrade.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jul 24 00:36:09 lisbook systemd[1]: Rebooting as result of failure.
```

It seems to be related to your WiFi kill switch (according to [this man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-rfkill.service.html)). Can you disable or uninstall that service and try again? Then reinstall when done?

(I am aware this would be better off as a comment, but it is too long and has odd formatting.)

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: Is there a new error?

Comment: New gist: https://gist.github.com/enedil/7121c8d7920dc737922be2ecd686c028

Comment: Now I see "dnf-system-upgrade.service: Failed with result 'resources'." where this *might* help: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2016-February/468518.html